# how to material ui dropdown multiple columns in react js

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

[How can I create a Material UI with the dropdown box shown in this photo? Only Material UI React JS (Java Script)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXJbH.png)

How can I use the backend to display the data of the first column and the second column?

Only Material UI React JS (Java Script)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Complete code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1p07JLZmZuoR1kA8xQhs3VSjJrQp4eGMF/view?usp=sharing)

complete solution check and "----" using it means change file create new file copy and past

Comment: how to primeReact ui dropdown multiple columns in react js